# Delete suspicious file protected by wininit.exe

Tags: windows-7, security

Today I've ran Task Manager and saw suspicious activity of sc.exe and conhost.exe.
I run ProcMon.exe and I saw that sc.exe was started by BrowserProtect.exe which is located in this folder:
`C:\ProgramData\BrowserProtect\2.5.1005.80\{c16c1ccb-7046-4e5c-a2f3-533ad2fec8e8}`
I didn't install it and I want to remove it.
I tried to delete it but I couldn't, because it was being used by `WinInit.exe`.
I know that I can delete it using bootable CD/DVD/USB device, but currently I have none of them with me.

How can I delete it manually?

Comment: What you are doing can damage Windows if you don't know what you are doing. It is not the correct way to remove a program. That program appears to be anti-Highjack software for all browsers. Have you tried to uninstall it from the Control Panel? Also, have you ran any malware/spyware scans to know it is malicious?

Comment: The file is connected to PerformerSoft LLC.  Sounds like you installed adware on your computer.  Do a clean boot.

Comment: I've the same problem. @CharlieRB I've tried to uninstall it from Control Panel and from it's Uninstall.exe. It simply removes it's name from installed-programs list, but doesn't remove it's files.
And if i try Uninstall.exe, it doesn't seem to run.

Comment: Did you try deleting it in Safe Mode? I also suggest running MalwareBytes and see if it detects anything.

Comment: I couldn't delete it in safe mode. Also I've Kaspersky Internet Security 2013 with latest bases, but it tells me there's no virus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try **Unlocker** or **Sysinternals' Handle.exe**. They helped me many times.

Run them **as administrator** and try to stop Wininit.exe's access to that file.
Also get privileges of that file from file Properties.
After doing these you'll probably be able to delete that file.

Comment: Thanks, it helped me. I was using them without running them as administrator.

Answer (score 0):

`BrowserProtect.exe` is a suspicious program, but you can remove it like a standard program.  Go into Remove Programs and Uninstall Browser Manager.  You'll have to complete a captcha to complete the uninstall.

Description of the program is [here](http://en.wiki.freefixer.com/wiki/Browsermngr.PerformerSoft).

Comment: I did it first of all. It only removed its name from installed programs list, but didn't remove itself and its files.